# Room cоздает все поля таблицы кроме одного

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, room

Компилируется без ошибок, но при запуске приложения в таблице отсутствует одно поле.

код класса

```
@Entity(tableName = "basestation")
data class BaseStation(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0,
    var operator: String = "",
    var Number: Int = 0,
    var Phone: Int = 0,
    var Vendor: Int = 0,
    var address: String = "no data",
    var lat: Double = 0.0,
    var long: Double = 0.0,
    var AZ: Int = 0,
    var type: String = "no data",
    var RAD: Int = 0,
    var SEC: Int = 0
)
```

версия SDK 33
версия room 2.5.0
После запуска на эмуляторе загружаю данные из csv-файла, в файле все столбцы заполнены, но при просмотре БД через App Inspection поля "long" просто нет

**UPD**

Тестировал в Android Studio Electric Eel в двух ОС - Windows 10 и Kubuntu 22.04. На винде всё ок, а в кубунте эмулятор ведёт себя иначе. Эмуляторы в обоих случаях почти идентичны - API 29, Pixel 2.

Comment: может покажете что при запуске происходит?

Comment: При запуске происходит ровным счетом... ничего. Всё работает штатно, никаких ошибок не выходит, приложение не крашится, при импорте из файла ошибок нет. Просто в таблице нет этого поля, при запросе в БД приходит ответ и в long записывается значение по-умолчанию - "0.0"

Comment: Возможно у вас конфликты чего-то с чем-то. Kotlina с кодогенерацией в Java или вы используете имена переменных которые являются ключевыми словами в котлине, Java или sql. Ну или просто версия БД у вас старая (т.е вы меняли схему БД). Проверьте последнее удалив БД очисткой данных приложения.

Comment: Добавил конкретики - ПО ведёт себя по разному в схожих эмуляторах в одинаковых IDE в разных ОС - на винде и линуксе